# How to calculate subnet mask from IP Gateway

Tags: ipv4, subnet

Suppose I was given this IP gateway :

```
199.141.27.129/26
```

How can I tell the subnet mask from the `/26`? Sometimes I notice this, for example : IP 150.10.10.10 with a mask 255.255.252.0 can be written 150.10.10.10/22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number (26) is the number of bits in the mask:

```
11111111.11111111.11111111.11000000
```

Convert it back to decimal:

```
255.255.255.192
```

Comment: AH, I see, so the number(x) means there will be x-consecutive-bits in a 32 bits string correct?

Comment: Correct! An IP address is 32 bits long, and so is a mask.